# How to use solely base path address?

Tags: asp.net-core, url

I have ASP.Net Core app which I would like to run in two instances. Currently I am testing one instance to sort out the base address problem.

In "Startup.Configure" I added as first line:

```
            app.UsePathBase("/cam1");
```

And it works, in sense, when I request something like "https://localhost:5011/cam1/proc/requests/about" it is correctly handled. The problem for me is that if I skip "cam1" part in the address it is handled "correctly" as well -- this is not my intention, I would like to solely use path base, and nothing else. And here it looks like two addressing are active -- one using path base I provided and the other one not using path base provided.

How to use solely provided base path, and nothing else? In this example anything not starting with "https://localhost:5011/cam1/" should not be picked up by the running instance  at all.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.UsePathBase()` just tell the your app "/caml" will also be ok,
if you want to force the path contain "/caml",try add `[Route("caml/[controller]/[action]")]` on your  controller
[image]
if you want set it globally,try to set it as below(.net 6):

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "~/caml/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Comment: Thank you. I am still looking how to do it globally, because with this approach I would have to shift one controller after another. Once I add new one I have to remember to add this prefix as well. So it does not scale up nicely.

Comment: I've updated my answer,please check it